# Where can I find data on aircraft?

Tags: data-request, transportation

I'm a student working on Blended-Wing-Body(BWB) shape optimization. Does anyone know how can I get wind tunnel data or other data on BWB? Is there open data for aircraft design?

Answer (score 3):

NASA does quite a bit of aircraft testing.  (It's the National **Aeronautics** and Space Administration, after all).

I'm not familiar with repositories of that sort of data, but you can find technical papers, including those on Blended Wing Bodies in the [NASA Technical Report Server](http://www.sti.nasa.gov/), and that would give you contacts to request the data if it wasn't specifically deposited separately.

(disclaimer: I work at a NASA center)